# Conditionals in external functions not working

Tags: php, forms, function, conditional-statements, external

This has been bugging me and I can't seem to figure out how to get around it.  Say I have an index.php that includes another page dostuff.php that's just a big function.  On my index page I have a conditional that gets called by a button in a form:

---index.php---

```
<?php
include 'dostuff.php';

if (isset($_POST['test'])) {
    test();
}

echo '<form id="test" method="post" action="'.htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).'">'.PHP_EOL;
echo '<button name="test" form="test" type="submit" value="test">Test</button>'.PHP_EOL;
echo '</form>'.PHP_EOL;
```

In my included function I have another form that calls another conditional within the function.

---dostuff.php---

```
<?php
function test() {
    if (isset($_POST['dostuff'])) {
        echo '<h1>Testing Do Stuff.</h1>';
    }

    echo '<form id="dostuff" method="post" action="'.htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).'">'.PHP_EOL;
    echo '<button name="dostuff" form="dostuff" type="submit" value="dostuff">Do Stuff!</button>'.PHP_EOL;
    echo '</form>'.PHP_EOL;
}
```

When I click the button on the index page the include is called and populates the page with its form.  However, when I click the button from the function, the form disappears and the conditional never executes.

Now, if I add the following to the index page:

```
print "CONTENT_TYPE: " . $_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'] . "<br>";
$data = readfile('php://input');
$contents = file_get_contents('php://input');
print "<br>";
print "DATA: <pre>";
var_dump($contents);
var_dump($data);
var_dump($_POST);
print "</pre>";
```

Clearly the form button is being called as verified by the var_dump call but the conditonal never executes.

```
CONTENT_TYPE: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
dostuff=dostuff
DATA:

string(15) "dostuff=dostuff"
int(15)
array(1) {
  ["dostuff"]=>
  string(7) "dostuff"
}
```

I searched here and just about everywhere else for an answer to this to no avail, so my question is why won't anything inside the conditionals work?  This seems very odd to me so I cobbled this together to test with.

Comment: I can't answer why, but I can at least confirm you are right.

Comment: Why are you executing the HTML content twice? If you really want just to execute the HTML content that is in the test function, then just put an `exit()` function after the `test()` function

Comment: I'm just testing things right now but I do agree that exit() might be a good thing if desired.  The problem with exit() is that if it's called, the test button goes away.  What if I don't want that?  Do I have to make another form in my function to add it back?

Answer (score 0):

It's just pure logic - it'll be a lot clearer if you make your forms use `method="GET"` instead of POST.

When you load it in the beginning you click on the button named "test" and so you have a $_POST['test'] value when you load the next time.

Your code looks like this in index.php:

```
if (isset($_POST['test'])) {
    test();
}
```

so of course test() is called and you see your HTML from dostuff.php.

The button in dostuff.php is named "dostuff" so when you push that button the form is loaded again with a value in $_POST['dostuff'] ''BUT NO VALUE IN `$_POST['test']`!!''

Once again your logic at the top of index.php is this:

```
if (isset($_POST['test'])) {
    test();
}
```

and since there is no value in $_POST['test'] your `test()` function never gets called and you never see the button you're expecting.

Really - change your forms to `GET` (you'll have to use $_GET or $_REQUEST instead of $_POST) so you can see exactly what is set each time without having to resort to all the fancy file reading and I think it'll be really clear.

Comment: I changed to GET and I do see what you're saying but I still can't see how to do the logic to get dostuff into index.php.  I'm kind of burnt out trying to get this to behave as I'd like so maybe I can't see the forest for the trees.

Comment: Erm, your question as stated is asking why your form doesn't show ("my question is why won't anything inside the conditionals work") - which is what I answered. If you have another question in mind you haven't stated it above... (And it's kind of bad form to change your question after the fact...)

Comment: The question hasn't changed, see below as what I have to show doesn't fit in comments.

Comment: See below what? I see a lot of stuff describing what you are seeing and then you state what your question is, but nowhere do I see that you've said anything about what you WANT to see. Am I missing it?

Comment: Run index.php with dostuff.php as is and the conditional on index.php causes the form in dostuff.php to not work.  Comment out the conditional if statement in index.php and the form in dostuff.php works.  That was the question and I showed the ouput to give a visual on the fact that the test button outputs the same code to the page but when the conditional if is introduced the same output code does not work.  What I'd like to know, basically, is how to get it to work given the conditional if statement.

Answer (score 0):

The question hasn't changed, see below as what I have to show doesn't fit in comments.

If I'm in index.php and I view my source, I get this:

```
<form id="test" method="get" action="/test/index.php">
    <button name="test" form="test" type="submit" value="test">Test</button>
</form>
```

If I click test I now get:

```
<form id="dostuff" method="get" action="/test/index.php">
    <button name="dostuff" form="dostuff" type="submit" value="dostuff">Do Stuff!</button>
</form>
<form id="test" method="get" action="/test/index.php">
    <button name="test" form="test" type="submit" value="test">Test</button>
</form>
```

If I use a condition to call my function I get nothing back.  If I eliminate the condition on index.php, and just call test(); I get back:

```
<form id="dostuff" method="get" action="/test/index.php">
    <button name="dostuff" form="dostuff" type="submit" value="dostuff">Do Stuff!</button>
</form>
<form id="test" method="get" action="/test/index.php">
    <button name="test" form="test" type="submit" value="test">Test</button>
</form>
```

Now if I click "Do Stuff!" I get back:

```
<h1>Testing Do Stuff.</h1>
<form id="dostuff" method="get" action="/test/index.php">
    <button name="dostuff" form="dostuff" type="submit" value="dostuff">Do Stuff!</button>
</form>
<form id="test" method="get" action="/test/index.php">
    <button name="test" form="test" type="submit" value="test">Test</button>
</form>
```

So, the question remains the same.  Why doesn't this work?

Comment: I explained why it's doing what it's doing. You still haven't explained what you WANT to happen!

Comment: I want to access a function (or different functions) based on the condition of a button press(s).  I thought I had illustrated this succinctly with my example but apparently not.